# Moving Object Origin but not the Object itself

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, shortcut

It appears my origins are detached from my object and not affecting the object itself. I have never seen this "Gizmo" show up before until now and I am afraid I hit something accidentally to cause this and I am not too sure what shortcut I pressed.

Let me know if anyone knows what this is called!

See attached screenshots to see me rotating an object but the origin just changes and not the object.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Affect Only Orign checkbox is on Sidebar > Tool tab > Options > Transform

[image]

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the shortcut is "CTRL" + "." (dot - not the one on the numpad) if you ever wonder how you enabled it

Comment: @Gorgious I have no shortcut on in.